# (Play 2.5) How do you define json format for type alias of an Option?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, type-alias

```
case class ClassA(myObjectType: TypeA.myTypeAlias)

object ClassA {

  implicit def jsonFormat: Format[ClassA] = Json.format[ClassA]

}

object TypeA {

  type myTypeAlias = Option[String]
}
```

I get a compile error of `No implicit format for typeA.myObjectType available.`

How do you define the JSON Format ?

Comment: Where are you actually getting the compiler error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error comes from the automatic implicit generation macro in [`play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.scala` (line 164 in Play 2.5.0-RC2)](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/58a150d712bdf3bf4d14709569afcfd9ea97fb7f/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala#L164).

This code doesn't dealias types before analyzing them, so it can't even infer that `TypeA.myTypeAlias` is an `Option`.

One thing you can do is specify an implicit `Format[myTypeAlias]`:

```
object ClassA {
  implicit val myTypeAliasFormat: Format[TypeA.myTypeAlias] = Format.optionWithNull
  implicit def jsonFormat: Format[ClassA] = Json.format[ClassA]
}
```

or

```
object TypeA {
  type myTypeAlias = Option[String]
  implicit val myTypeAliasFormat: Format[myTypeAlias] = Format.optionWithNull
}

object ClassA {
  import TypeA.myTypeAliasFormat
  implicit def jsonFormat: Format[ClassA] = Json.format[ClassA]
}
```

Note that it will convert JSON `null` to `None`, yield an error if the path is missing, and serialize `None` as JSON `null`.

I believe, it's not possible to achieve the behaviour to interpret missing paths as `None`, and skip serializing `None`, when using type aliases and automatic implicit generation with `Json.format`. You'd have to manually write a JSON `Format` if you want that behaviour.