# scala persisting seq with Options

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I have

```
case class ProcessSteps(stepsData: Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel])
```

This Seqence could have empty ProcessStepTemplatesModel

Now when I want to persist the the array like this:

```
request.body.asJson.foreach(f = _.validate[ProcessSteps] match {
      case JsSuccess(processSteps, _) =>
        // PROBLEM HIER
        processSteps.stepsData.foreach(processStep => processTemplateDTO.addProcessStepTemplateToProcessTemplate(processStep, processId).map {
```

I got an error because of the null values.

Is there a way to scip the null values and only persis the ones which are not null?

Im running a scala Playframework app with slick as database mapper

Thanks

Comment: How about using an `Option[Seq[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]` instead of null? Or using `Seq.empty[T]` as a default value?

Comment: Option[Seq is not possible I don't want to persist null values, I want to skip them

Comment: How about processSteps.stepsData.filter( _ != null).foreach(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to wrap `ProcessStepTemplatesModel` in `Option` to indicate there could be `null` values: 
`case class ProcessSteps(stepsData: Seq[Option[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]])`, 
then `filter(_.isDefined)` your sequence to have only existing (non-nullable) steps and perform the rest of the code safely.

Comment: Hi we tried this as well, but then I got an error here `implicit val ProcessStepsFormat: OFormat[ProcessSteps] = Json.format[ProcessSteps]`

Comment: Error is:  No implicit format for Seq[Option[models.ProcessStepTemplatesModel]] available.

Comment: I have a feeling that implicit format for operating with this object should be overriden and defined by yourself. Looks like guyz in [this thread](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/5196) discuss the relevant issue, aren't they?

Comment: It should, according to [the 2.5 docs paragraph about reading options](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24#Reading-Options) and to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35768077/2695569) which is pretty similar to your case i think